# Remove unnecessary css font-face font type

Tags: css, fonts

I have a template that use a font via `font-face` in css with `font-face` it call all type of `.eot .svg .ttf .woff .woff2 .otf` fonts.

```
1. Do I really need all of them? because size of them are 100 between 300kb
2. Browsers must download all of them when opens a webpage?
```

I want display the font correctly on android/IE/chorme/firfox/ios.

Comment: you can trivially check if the browser are grabbing them all but looking at your server's access log while hitting the site in various browsers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to load all for every browser.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('PT Sans'),
         local('PTSans-Regular'),      
         url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptsans/v8/JX7MlXqjSJNjQvI4heMMGvY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptsans/v8/LKf8nhXsWg5ybwEGXk8UBQ.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/PT_Sans-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),  
         url('../fonts/PT_Sans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),  
         url('../fonts/PT_Sans-Web-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

This is a bit modified code from Google fonts, it is load first file on the list (woff2) and if browser supports it it is not loading next ones.

Do you really need all of them?
Depends which browser you want to support. You can check which files are supported where by use [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff2)